# finding points of discontinuity of the function $f(x) = \frac{x}{\sin x} $.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, continuity

finding points of discontinuity of the function $f(x) = \frac{x}{\sin x} $.

**My answer is:**
The point of discontinuity is $0$ and it is a removable discontinuity because the limit is 1, am I correct?

Comment: Partially, but there are a lot more.

Comment: @T.Bongers  you mean $n\pi$ for every integer n?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: but why they are discontinuities, they did not give us zero in the denominator @T.Bongers

Comment: What do you mean "they did not give us zero in the denominator"? They do.

Comment: These points are not in the domain of the function - it is continuous on its whole domain.

Comment: why this points are not in the domain of the function? how they give us zero in the denominator?@T.Bongers

Comment: why this points are not in the domain of the function? how they give us zero in the denominator?@mwt

Comment: because values of the function at these points are undefined (what should $f(\pi)$ be equal to?)

Comment: it will be $0/\pi$ which is an acceptable value of the function.@mwt

Comment: Are we talking about the same function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that we expect a discontinuity everytime the denominator, i.e., $\sin x$, is $0$. This occurs when $x=n\pi$ for some $n\in\mathbb Z$.

Now note that when $n\neq0$, the numerator of the function will approach $n\pi$ while the denominator will approach $0$. Hence, these are not removable discontinuities but rather vertical asymptotes.

On the other hand, when $n=0$, then $\lim_{x\to0}\frac x{\sin x} = 1$, so this is a removable discontinuity.

Comment: yeah sorry all the time I was thinking of the function as $\sin x  /x$ which I think its point of discontinuity is only 0...... correct?

Comment: @mwt Please reread. I said "approach".

Comment: mwt is right. The question does not contain information where $f$ is defined, but the maximal domain is $D = \mathbb{R} \setminus \{ n\pi \mid n \in \mathbb{R} \}$ . $f$  is continuous on $D$. It cannot be discontinuous at points where it is not defined. However, it has a continuous extension to $D_0 = D \cup \{ 0 \}$ (set $f(0)=1$), but none to a bigger $D \supsetneqq D_0$. In fact, any definition of $f(n\pi)$ makes the extended function discontinuous at $n\pi$.

Comment: have you read my first comment ? all the time my brain was thinking of the reciprocal of the given function ....... could you answer my first comment please?

Comment: @Happy yes indeed

Comment: @Paul Frost. This function is defined almost everywhere. The notion of continuity can be naturally extended to functions that are defined almost everywhere.

Comment: @PaulFrost I agree with Albert. Usually, implicit in high school level questions on discontinuity is that the domain is extended to be contiguous. Otherwise, the questions wouldn't be interesting.